# Remove all public IP from the VM's that are running or not running in azure by PS Script

Tags: powershell, azure

#

I found some solution but not 100%, I got this script that shows me the name of all the VM's in all RG's and the status if it's running or deallocated. but now I need to create a command that will remove public IP from a specific VM's that are running or deallocated.

```
$RGs = Get-AzureRMResourceGroup
foreach($RG in $RGs)
{
    $VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $RG.ResourceGroupName
    foreach($VM in $VMs)
    {
        $VMDetail = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $RG.ResourceGroupName -Name $VM.Name -Status
        foreach ($VMStatus in $VMDetail.Statuses)
        { 
            if($VMStatus.Code -like "PowerState/*")
            {
                $VMStatusDetail = $VMStatus.DisplayStatus
            }
        }
        write-output $VM.Name $VMStatusDetail
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way does it "seems to be not working"? That is a very mediocre attempt at troubleshooting

Comment: updated the post

Comment: Does this help? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2016/07/01/powertip-get-the-public-ip-of-an-azure-vm-with-powershell/

Comment: That's only finding the NIC but I want to remove the public IP from all the VM's that are deallocated or running by my choice.
The first script i posted find me all the VM's and shows me if they are running or deallocated.
Now i need a command that will remove NIC's from specific VM's that are deallocated or running.

Comment: Is it listing the NIC's that have public IP's? Looking at my VM's it seems that public IP's are a property of the NIC

Comment: As you say "I need to create a command that will remove public IP from a specific VM's that are running or deallocated". First, you did not filter that. Second, there are some statuses in VMDetail.Statuses, but you just need $VMDetail.Statuses[1]. So use $VMDetail.Statuses[1] instead of foreach.